# Custom Button in TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TabControl and a UserControl (lets call it `myUserControl`) that are fitted inside StackPanel.

```
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
           <userControls:myUserControl/>
           <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Top">
               <TabItem>
                   // ...
               </TabItem>
               <TabItem>
                   // ...
               </TabItem>
          </TabControl>
      </StackPanel>
```

`myUserControl` is a container for another 2 UserControls :

```
    <Grid>
        <local:control1 />
        <local:control2 />
    </Grid>
```

I need to add a button to `control1` so that it will fit in the same area where TabItems are, but alligned to the other side (like shown on the picture below)
[image: i need to place a button where red rectangle is, but it must be inside control1]

I would be really glad if I could get some advice on how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mm8 but this button belongs to control1 and is handled in corresponding viewmodel. if i extract these buttons, it will lead to unwanted references to parent controls.

Comment: @mm8 i only need it too look like its int the same row at tab items. I've added negative margin to my tabControl and this solved my visual issue, but button became unclickable. Is there a way to make it clickable as well as tabItems?

Comment: I got it. My TabControl style had transparent background, thats why it wasnt click-though. I replaced Transparent with {x:null} and it all worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always an answer got into my head just in few minutes after posting this question)

All I have to do is just apply negative margin to my TabControl and make sure that its background is set to `NULL` (it is by default), so it will be a click-through